# Type of expression ambiguous without more context (putData)

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting an error in the line of code for putData saying "Type of expression ambiguous without more context".

Are there any suggestions for this problem? Please let me know, and thank you!

```
 @IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if let message = messageTextField.text{
            if imageAdded && message != " " {
                // Upload the image
                
                let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
                
                if let image = imageView.image {
                    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
                        imagesFolder.child(imageName).putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                            if let error = error {
                                self.presentAlert(alert: error.localizedDescription)
                                
                            } else {
                                // Segue to next view controller
                                
                            if let downloadURL = metadata?.download.url {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectReceiverSegue", sender: downloadURL)
                                 }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // We are missing something
               presentAlert(alert: "You must provide an image and a amessage for your time.")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried changing putData to put but it tells me that it was changed in the new version of Xcode. I also tried looking for other options to download the URL in that line but I come back to the same issue.

If I change the code `metadata?.download.url` to `metadata?.description` in the if let downloadURL line the error gets fixed but the application does not show me the image.

Comment: Any time you get an ambiguous expression, remove parts of the code until the error goes away, or the error becomes more clear. Eventually it will point you to your mistake.